# Is there a way to get a git repo for a single file or folder within another repo?

Tags: git, github

I have read about submodules and I don't think that solves my probelm.

PC1: Large Git Repo on server with perl scripts
Server1: Uses only 1 perl script from within the PC1 repo

How do we integrate so that only that file or folder used by Server 1 is included in the repo in Server1.

Pushes / Pulls (revisions) of that folder or file must integrgate the 2 repos.
When pulling on Server1 I just want to pull chagnges to that file or folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single folder in your repo can have a diffrent git repo. We use the same principal.
For example this is our directory structure

```
/
/.git
/src
/files
/folder
/whatever
/api
  /api/.git
```

In this case we have a git repo in our root and a second git repo for our API. I'm not sure if this is possible for a single file but you could always create a folder with a single file in it.

When in '/api' if we use 'git pull' it detects the API repo. In any other folder it detects the 'root' repo.

Not exactly what you want but perhaps you didn't think on this solution.

Comment: Will I need to commit and push and pull independently of the parent git repo?

Comment: @StevieG, yes. The inner repository is completely separate from the outer one.

Comment: Yes, that is the only way I know always works. If you want you can create a single batch script that executes 2 git-pull commands for both folders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any proper way that it can be done, but a workaround might be to create a branch which has only this one file and push only this branch to the server. Everytime you make change to the script that server repo has, just update that in this branch and push.

Since the files are same git reuses the blob! You are just using a different way to reference it!